# Make a survey page not printable with CSS

Tags: html, css, web

Hey I am building a survey website for a university project.
I am using a tool called unipark(tivian) and I can upload CSS pages for my survey.
How can I male it that the page is totally normal but when someone clicks on „print“ to screenshot the page it appears empty for them.
I need to do that because of the copyright security.
Thanks in advance :)

I tried it with a css file like this:

```
body {display: none;}
```

But now the whole page is empty from the beginning.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having access to my HTML page? The tool I am using creates a bunch of .tpl files but I don't know where I should insert the "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css"/>"
part

Comment: Nvm I found the HTML and made it work! Thanks for your links!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following css (make it a new print.css file for example):

```
/* Hide all elements when printing */
body {
    display: none;
}

/* Show a message indicating that printing is not allowed */ 
@media print {   
    body::before {
        content: "Printing is not allowed due to copyright restrictions.";
        display: block;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin: 50px;
} }
```

Then add the following to your file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

When you add `media="print"` to the html, it will be only applied when page is being printed.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having access to my HTML page? The tool I am using creates a bunch of .tpl files but I don't know where I should insert the "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css"/>" part –

Comment: Nvm I found the html part and made it work! Thanks for your help

Comment: Really all that's needed is @media print { * {display: none; }}